How to reload a page indefinitely?
The code below reload a page just once after initial page rendering (loading). It does not reload the page after first reload request was made. I want to know how to reload a page indefinitely. In other words, each time a user make a page reload request then it should happen at all time.
customer.component.ts
constructor(private router: Router ) {
  this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = () => {
   return false;
  };
}

pageReload(){
  this.router.navigate(['/customer'], { queryParams: { namevar: this.namevar } });
}

html
 <button (click)="pageReload()" > Refresh</button>


The obvious solution would be window.location.reload(). Did you try it?

@JSON Derulo, sorry your suggestion does not meet my requirement. It's reloading the entire website. My request is to reload a particular page (customer component), the codes l had supplied in the question actually work just once, and after that it does not reload any further

Try the below code, which reloads the component. The onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' and skipLocationChange: true trigger the component reload without refresh of page.
pageReload() {
  this.router.navigateByUrl(`${window.location.pathname}`, {
    onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload',
    skipLocationChange: true,
  });
}


I imported the below line of code into app module and this solved my problem in the above question. The current page is reloading indefinitely.
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload' })

